# Sharing subplot x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, sharing

After a ***lot*** of fighting and watching youtube tutorials I have been able to achieve my goal of creating a figure window, with a unique name and 4 subplots.

The method I used was `add_subplot` because I understand the code better rather than unpacking tuples method i.e. fig, ...

The last bit I am trying to do is share my x axis and after a lot of playing around i.e. trying to insert the code `sharex="Cols"` or `sharex = True` I have had no success.

My complete code is as follows:-

```
import pandas
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

x = numpy.linspace(0, 2*numpy.pi, 400)
y = numpy.sin(x**2)
yy = numpy.sin(x**2+3)

My_Figure_Window = pyplot.figure("Title Of Figure Window")
pyplot.style.use("ggplot")
My_Figure_Window.suptitle("Main Title")

Sub_Plot_Rows = 4
Sub_Plot_Cols = 1

Wall = My_Figure_Window.add_subplot(Sub_Plot_Rows, Sub_Plot_Cols, 1)
Wall.plot(x, y, color="r", label='Line 1')
Wall.plot(x, yy, color="b", label='Line 2')
pyplot.ylabel("Ylabel")
Wall.get_legend_handles_labels()
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()

Sidewalk = My_Figure_Window.add_subplot(Sub_Plot_Rows, Sub_Plot_Cols, 2)
Sidewalk.plot(x, y, label='Line 3')
Sidewalk.plot(x, yy, label='Line 4')
pyplot.ylabel("Ylabel")
Sidewalk.get_legend_handles_labels()
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()

HeadWall = My_Figure_Window.add_subplot(Sub_Plot_Rows, Sub_Plot_Cols, 3)
HeadWall.plot(x, y, label='Line 5')
HeadWall.plot(x, yy, label='Line 6')
pyplot.ylabel("Ylabel")
HeadWall.get_legend_handles_labels()
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()

SideTank = My_Figure_Window.add_subplot(Sub_Plot_Rows, Sub_Plot_Cols, 4)
SideTank.plot(x, y, label='Line 7')
SideTank.plot(x, yy, label='Line 8')
pyplot.ylabel("Ylabel")
SideTank.get_legend_handles_labels()
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

Can anyone just point me in the right direction as to where / how I can share my X axis for all these subplots?

On a side note I have realized that the code `pyplot.show()` does not have any affect yet everyone includes it?

Comment: As a sidenote, `SideTank.get_legend_handles_labels()` does nothing on its own: it eturns objects that you can pass to another call to legend. Typically, it's sufficient to simply call axes.legend(), which I believe calls get_legend_handles_labels():

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html

Comment: You only need call `pyplot.show()` once at the end of your code. [Here](https://pastebin.com/1mniC0KD) is a working sample.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to use matplotlib. The first is the pyplot "stateful" API, where you make calls like `pyplot.legend()`, and the other is an object-oriented API, where you make calls like `SideTank.get_handles_labels(). Both are fine, but mixing them too much sometimes leads to confusion. This is the problem in your case. For instance,

```
SideTank.get_legend_handles_labels()
pyplot.legend()
```

The first call is part of the OO API, the second is the pyplot one. You probably want to use `SideTank.legend()` if you're using the OO API, and `pyplot.legend()` only if you're using the Pyplot API.

If you want to use the pyplot API:

- https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html is a powerful reference.

If you want to use the OO API:

- https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html
- https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes

Here are a few ways to accomplish twinned axes:

```
# This will create a Figure and a list of 4 axes objects. All of those axes objects will have sharex X axes
figure, axes = pyplot.subplots(nrows=4, sharex=True)

axes[0].plot((0, 1), (0, 1))
axes[1].plot((0, 2), (0, 1))
axes[2].plot((0, 0.5), (0, 1))
axes[3].plot((1, 1.5), (0, 1))
```

```
# Create a figure
fig = pyplot.figure()

# Use that figure to create a first subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 1)
# Make the following subplots twin that subplot's x axis.
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 2, sharex = ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 3, sharex = ax1)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 4, sharex = ax1)

ax1.plot((0, 1), (0, 1))
ax2.plot((0, 2), (0, 1))
ax3.plot((0, 0.5), (0, 1))
ax4.plot((1, 1.5), (0, 1))
```

If you want to use the pyplot API, it'll look something like this.

```
# Create a current figure and subplot
pyplot.figure()
pyplot.subplot(4, 1, 1)

# Plot something in the current subplot
pyplot.plot((0, 1), (0, 1))

# short for "get current axes"
# This returns an Axis, so we're dipping into the OO API; it's not uncommon to need to
# do that to do more advanced things, but it's a signal to be careful!
share_handle = pyplot.gca() 

# Select a new subplot, and tell it to share its x axis with the first subplot.
pyplot.subplot(4, 1, 2, sharex = share_handle)
pyplot.plot((0, 2), (0, 1))

pyplot.subplot(4, 1, 3, sharex = share_handle)
pyplot.plot((0, 0.5), (0, 1))

pyplot.subplot(4, 1, 4, sharex = share_handle)
pyplot.plot((1, 1.5), (0, 1))
```

All of these will create something like the following:

[image: The results of the above code in Jupyter. Four plots, each with a line covering various segments of a shared X axis.]

On your secondary question, `pyplot.show()` displays *figures* not subplots. Thus, you probably only want to call it once, when you're all done setting up the entire figure.